# How to store Texture/Texture2D or other Unity object in local user storage?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to store some information for the application (cache), which will be downloaded from server. I know, that I can serialise primitives, and store them like JSON or binary. But what can I do with Texture/Texture2D/AudioClip? Also there can be a problem, because I want to store them as a big huge object class (created by me).
Thank you very much for any reply. Sorry for such stupid question, I am very new to Unity and C# and trying to do my best.

I tried to create a binary from texture and store it, but it didn't go well.

```
[Serializable]
public class Book
{
    public class Page
    {
        public class Size
        {
            public float X { get; set; }
            public float Y { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomAnimation
        {
            public Texture[] Images { get; set; }
            public Size Size { get; set; }
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Texture Background { get; set; }
        public CustomAnimation[] Animations { get; set; }
        public AudioClip AudioClip { get; set; }
    }

    public Page[] Pages { get; set; }
}
```

This is the example of my structure. I would like to know, if it is possible to store it somehow on a device, or not

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "store it" on a device?

Comment: @jtate I mean to store it locally in mobile memory. if I close the application, it will remain in the memory without must of downloading again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two methods Texture2D.EncodeToPNG and Texture2D.EncodeToJPG that give you a byte array with binary representation of the texture (Texture2D.LoadImage performs the opposite process).

You can just save those byte[]s onto disk. If you want to embed them into jsons, I would suggest using a scheme like BASE64 encoding to get rid of non-printable characters

Answer (score 0):

When downloading the texture, use WWW object to download the texture. It will cache the file which you can load using the following method.

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload.html

Once the file is downloaded, you can use **Application.persistentDataPath** method to retrieve the texture files. They will be loaded in full resolution.

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html

I have used this method to load 360 photos at 4K resolution and it works great!

Hope this helps.